# How can Skype show "Invisible" when there is no Internet connection?

Tags: networking, skype, notification-area

How can this situation be possible:

[image]

As I understand it, Skype's *Invisible* status means that **I'm connected to Skype network** (can see messages sent from other users, can see their status) but others cannot see my status and see me as being offline.

So, how can Skype that I'm connected to Skype network if there is no Internet connection available and virtually every other program or service correctly claims that I'm offline?

Comment: Because you might be on a local network?

Comment: @mcalex The network icon seems to be saying that I'm not connected to any network, neither local nor external one (which is true in fact).